# Java Generics and Super Type Tokens

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I am trying to make the three following methods into one generic solution, I tried some ideas which compile but don't do well at runtime.

```java
public static List<User> parseToUsers(HttpResponse response) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String results = parseToString(response);
  return mapper.readValue(results, new TypeReference<List<User>>() {});
}

public static List<Record> parseToRecords(HttpResponse response) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String results = parseToString(response);
  return mapper.readValue(results, new TypeReference<List<Record>>() {});
}

public static Record parseToRecord(HttpResponse response) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String results = parseToString(response);
  return mapper.readValue(results, new TypeReference<Record>() {});;
}
```

I have also tried to understand this [blog post about Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

EDIT:

This is what I came up with so far:

```
public static <T> T parseJsonResponse(TypeReference<T> type, HttpResponse response) throws DroidException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String results = parseResponseToString(response);
    return readValue = mapper.readValue(results, type);
}
```

Then I call it like this.

```
parseJsonResponseToList(new TypeReference<List<Record>>() {}, response)
```

Not really satisfieng.Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you really mean C++ ? The code you gave is in C#.

Comment: Oups ;). It could have been C# as well, or not far: I should have paid attention to the case of the first letter of your function names.

Comment: ObjectMapper is your own definition class or the third party component?

Comment: its from the jackson lib

Comment: i edited the question, added a possible answer

Comment: Because of type erasure, I think parseToUsers and parseToRecords do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Your not going to get much better than the code you edited in. That method is pretty much standard for handling deserialization of genericized lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what exactly is the problem? In what way do you not like it?

Jackson has other ways for constructing generic types; so perhaps what are looking for is along lines of:

```
public List<T> listOf(String json, Class<T> elementType) {
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // should (re)use static instance for perf!
   JavaType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, elementType);
   return mapper.readValue(json, listType);
}
```

`TypeFactory` can be used to programmatically construct types that use generics -- return type is `JavaType`, because basic Java `Class` is type-erased.
`TypeFactory` is actually used to convert `TypeReference` to `JavaType` internally as well.

**EDIT**

As to regular, non-Collection/Map types, it's really quite simple:

```
public T parseSingle(Class<T> cls, InputStream src) throws IOException {
  return mapper.readValue(src, cls);
}
```

(you also do NOT want to read contents as String -- not only is it slow, but it's easy to mess up character encodings, so if possible, feed `InputStream` or `byte[]` instead)

Comment: yeah im pretty confused by the jackson lib anyways :P, so ObjectMapper is thread safe? the use case we have here is that we also want to be able to parse to a single User instead of a List<User>

Comment: Have you read the FAQ (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ)? Yes, it is thread-safe (first hit with google "jackson thread safe", FWIW).

Comment: As to regular vs List: for non-Collection types, you need not bother with either `TypeReference` of `TypeFactory`: just pass the Class and it will "just work"

Comment: i just looked at the api documentation and i couldnt read threadsafe there. I have the String return type because i want to make sure others dont forget to consume the HttpResponse. So i wrapped all the access to Http Layer. But i checked and i guess i can make the methods return byte[] instead and since String Constructor takes byte[] as an argument it should work out. thanks alot!

Comment: Hmm but then it would be easier to mess up character encoding because if someone uses the String Constructor without charset parameter... Is the performance increase significant? I mean in the end im doing the transformation on the client. So i think making sure the encoding isnt messed up is more important? what do you think?

Comment: Yes, never ever construct String without specifying encoding explicitly. But why are you constructing a String? For data-binding, using `byte[]` is better anyway, and `ObjectMapper` is happy to take one (InputStream, Reader, URL, String are all fine too)

Comment: ty, just refactored my http wrapper, constructing strings was a bad design decision :) so im passing an inputstream to the readValue method now. how does objectmapper know which charset the inputstream has? im a lil bit confused now if there might come up a charset issue.

Comment: It can reliably auto-detect it, using first couple of bytes, as per JSON specification -- there are only 3 legal encodings (UTF-8 / 16 / 32) to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your `ObjectMapper` and `TypeReference` classes do, so maybe this answer doesn't fit you all that well, but here's how I'd probably do it if I understand your situation at all:

```
public interface Parser<T> {
    public T parse(String results);
    public static class MapperParser<T> implements Parser<T> {
        private final TypeReference<T> type;
        public MapperParser(TypeReference<T> type) {this.type = type;}
        public T parse(String results) {
            return(new ObjectMapper().readValue(results, type));
        }
    }
    public static final Parser<List<User>> users = new MapperParser(new TypeReference<List<User>>());
    public static final Parser<List<Record>> records = new MapperParser(new TypeReference<List<Record>>());
    public static final Parser<Record> record = new MapperParser(new TypeReference<Record>());
}

/* And then, in the class you were in your question: */
public static <T> T parseJsonResponse(Parser<T> parser, HttpResponse response) {
    return(parser.parse(parseResponseToString(response)));
}
```

Then, you may call it as such:

```
parseJsonResponse(Parser.users, response)
```

Is that more to your liking?

Comment: that looks quite nice and is good inspiration but too much code for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my favorite solution, inspired by Dolda2000, i keep as is in my initial post and add an enum.

```
public enum TypeRef {
    RECORDS(new TypeReference<List<Record>>() {}), USERS(new TypeReference<List<User>>() {}), USER(new TypeReference<User>() {});

    private TypeReference<?>    type;

    private TypeRef(TypeReference<?> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public TypeReference<?> getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

and then instead of writing:

```
readJsonResponse(new TypeReference<List<Record>>() {}, response)
```

i can write:

```
readJsonResponse(TypeRef.RECORDS, response);
```

no magic going on but i like it more than wrapping it in another interface

Answer (score 0):

Ok after running into a compile error:

type parameters of T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object

i quit the over engeneering session and keep it simple

```
private static TypeReference<List<Record>>  RECORDS = new TypeReference<List<Record>>() {};

public static <T> T readJson(TypeReference<T> type, String text) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return readValue = mapper.readValue(text, type);
}
```

use it like this

```
readJson(RECORDS, text);
```

no enums, i just use static fields for the TypeReference and everyone can read the code easily without understanding TypeReference

thank you guys i learned something about over engeneering today :P