# How to get the Generic Type Parameter?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, generic-programming, type-parameter

Simply:

```
public static class MyClass<T> {
    // i don't want to keep an instance of T, if it is not necessary.
    // and it is not nice, not neat.

    // Or, let's say, the member are in the form of :
    ArrayList<T> mArrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
    // the problem of getting the generic type parameter is still present.
}

@Test
public final void test() {
    MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<Integer>();
    getParamType( myObject );
}

private static final <T> void getParamType(final MyClass<T> _myObject) {
    System.out.println(_myObject.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0]);    // T
    System.out.println(((T) new Object()).getClass());                  // class java.lang.Object
}
```

### How to let the code print `class java.lang.Integer`?

i know quite a few of stackoverflow threads are asking (and answering) about this. Yet they couldn't solve this question.

- i don't know why some need to call `getGenericSuperclass()` - as there is no inheritance involved in this simple case.
- And i can't cast it to `ParameterizedType` as well.

.

```
System.out.println((ParameterizedType) _myObject.getClass());
// Compile Error: Cannot cast from Class<capture#11-of ? extends TreeTest2.MyClass> to ParameterizedType

System.out.println((ParameterizedType) _myObject.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
// Runtime Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

---

Based on @Thomas's guide, i have found a ***work-around*** way to get `class java.lang.Integer`.

First, we create **an anonymous** (it need to be anonymous) sub-class of `MyClass<T>` in the testing code. (Which is weird. Why it only support sub-classes?)

```
@Test
public final void test() {
    MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<Integer>() {};  // Anonymous sub-class
    getParamType( myObject );
}
```

Then we can use the `getGenericSuperclass()` method to get a `Type` then cast it to `ParameterizedType` and afterwards uses `getActualTypeArguments()`:

```
private static final <T> void getParamType(final MyClass<T> _myObject) {
    System.out.println( ((ParameterizedType) _myObject.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0] );
}
```

It perfectly prints `class java.lang.Integer`.

#### This is **not-so-good** because the testing codes should simulate the actual situation, where users most likely won't keep creating meaningless sub-classes.

This approach is based on the idea of [the TypeReference class](http://gafter.blogspot.hk/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html). But i don't really know how to use it. I have tried `class MyClass<T> extends TypeReference<T>`. But i still have to create sub-class of `MyClass<T>` to have `TypeReference.getType()` prints `class java.lang.Integer`.

Please help, and thanks for any inputs, as the best approach is not here yet.

---

#### A further question based on the above workaround: Why only anonymous sub-class works?

```
public static class SubMyClass<T> extends MyClass<T>{}

@Test
public final void test() {
    MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<Integer>() {};  // Anonymous sub-class
    getParamType( myObject );               // class java.lang.Integer

    MyClass<Integer> mySubObject = new SubMyClass<Integer>();   // named sub-class
    getParamType( mySubObject );            // T
}
```

(`MyClass` and `getParamType()` unchanged.)

Answer (score 3):

This is sort of difficult, because Java deliberately can't do that ("type erasure").

The work-around is called [super type tokens](http://blog.crazybob.org/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html). There are also some threads on SO about that (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75175/1005481) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9613374/1005481)).

Comment: Thanks Thomas! The `TypeReference` class is new to me. Can i interpret why the `TypeReference<T>` can get its `T` because (1) it's abstract, thus force inheritance, and (2) only `Type java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass()` can be casted to `ParameterizedType`, thus we can use `getActualTypeArguments`?

Comment: If there is a method like `Type java.lang.Class.getGeneric_____class()` where we can do `((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGeneric____class()).getActualTypeArguments()` would be great, isn't it? Btw why Java have only the "get super" method that returns a `Type`?

Comment: Back to the original question. How to get `class java.lang.Integer` with the help of `TypeReference`? By `new TypeReference<List<String>>() {}.getType()` i can get `java.util.List<java.lang.String>` (but this is not useful, as it is not getting from the object). Then i let `class MyClass<T> extends TypeReference<T>` and by `myObject.getType()` i get only `T`. Thanks for guided me the way. Please help me to go a bit further.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a question like this, you should ask yourself, how would you do it without Generics? Because any Generics program can be converted into an equivalent program without Generics. (This conversion is called type erasure.) So if you cannot do it without Generics, you cannot do it with Generics either.

Your program without Generics looks like this:

```
public static class MyClass {
    ArrayList mArrayList = new ArrayList();
}

@Test
public final void test() {
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
    Integer result = getParamType( myObject ); // how would you implement getParamType()?
}
```

Comment: If there is no generics, how can we get the generics?

Comment: @midnite: It's not about the generics. It's about the logic of the program. For example, if you had made the constructor of `MyClass` take a parameter of type `Class<T>` which represents the class, and you store it in the class, then after erasure, you would see that you're doing `MyClass myObject = new MyClass(clazz);`, and you are storing a variable of type `Class` inside the class. From this you can see clearly why that works and your approach doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Keeping a `Class<T>` as a member field, i understand why it works. But i don't understand the opposite. Just like, having a member field `public T mField;`, we can also retrieve the `T` from `mField.getClass()` afterwards.

Comment: Moreover, why there is only `getGenericSuperclass()` but not `getGenericThisclass()`? This seems not logical.

Comment: @midnite: Generics is just a compile-time type checking thing. It is an illusion. It doesn't really "exist". You are asking for the type parameter because you see it in this illusion. I'm showing you what it is when you peel away the illusion, to show you that what you are looking at doesn't exist, and you need something else. The most important thing to remember is: When you add generics to a piece of code, it NEVER gives you the magical ability to do something that you couldn't do before Generics. That's why it's instructive to ask yourself how you would do it without Generics.

Comment: i like your idea. This is inspiring.

Comment: ok... i accept that Generics is an illusion. And i somehow can imaging Generics is a compile-time stuff. But... for Reflections, it doesn't obey the rule of the game, does it?

Comment: @midnite: Yes, well, reflection is for retrieving the metadata of the *declarations*, e.g. the fields and methods and their types, and the superclasses, etc. And so yes, you can retrieve generics in declarations (because it needs to be accessible in order for the compiler to type-check, since Java classes can be compiled separately). But generics in declarations is not really what your question is about.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a misguided feature called [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) that specifically prevents you from doing that.

Generic parameter information does not exist at runtime.

Instead, you can manually accept a `Class<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What do you mean by "manually accept a Class<T>"?

Comment: Add a `Class<T>` parameter to your constructor.

Comment: Erasure is a compromise. I would not call it misguided.

Comment: Is it, such that, we have to call `MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<Integer>(Integer.class);` when creating the object? This is dangerous as we can call `MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<Integer>(String.class);` which is valid as well.

Comment: @midnite not if you declare the parameter as `Class<T>`.

Comment: @Thomas Oh yes! my mistake :-x